# Регулярное выражение: три повторяющихся символа не обязательно подряд

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть строка "abanba";

В ней буквы a повторяются три раза, но не подряд. Как составить регулярное выражение, которое бы при использовании функции `test` возвращало `true` на такую строку?

`/[a]{3}/` - такое не работает, так как ищет только подряд буквы `a`, а нужно в любом месте именно три.

Comment: А вот такая строка - `abababa`, где `a` больше трёх, тоже должна пройти проверку?

Answer (score 2):

```
/^[^a]*a[^a]*a[^a]*a[^a]*$/
```

Ставим маяки на начало `^` и конец `$` строки, чтобы поиск требовал полное совпадение с маской, иначе включение 4-х букв "а" тоже будет валидным.

Внутри пишем три раза искомый символ, разделяя его любым количеством любых символов, кроме искомого: `[^a]*`. С флагами в конце выражения может понадобиться поиграться, в зависимости от языка.
Для проверки таких вещей я использую [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/), там нужно включить флаги `/gm` и вводить испытательные данные на разных строках.
Полная строка приобретёт вид:

```
/^[^a]*a[^a]*a[^a]*a[^a]*$/gm
```

Любой символ кроме искомого - это [^a]
Добавляем произвольное количество совпадений - [^a]*
Звёздочка (*) включает 0 и более вхождений, в то время как (+) требует не менее одного вхождения - это может пригодиться, если не допустимо включение "aa" подряд.

Понимаю, что не очень красиво, но не вижу лучшего решения

Comment: Можно немного сократить `^([^a]*a){3}[^a]*$`

Answer (score -1):

```
function search($string, $char = 'a')
{
    // ищем все совпадения переданного символа
    preg_match_all('/' . $char . '/', $string, $matches); 

    // если количество найденных совпадений - 3 то возвращаем true иначе false
    if (count($matches[0]) == 3)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

search('abanba', 'a'); // true
search('abanb', 'a'); // false
search('abanbaa', 'a'); // false
```

Пример написан на *PHP*. В других языках программирования такая фишка тоже есть.

Comment: Данное выражение не верное, в данном выражении и 4 `a` прокатит и 10,